# NSSM - Install service from command line with many arguments

Tags: service, command-line, arguments, nssm

I am trying to make a batch file that will create my service and struggling with how exactly to list each parameter.  I've researched this quite a bit and I can't seem to find the correct syntax.  This is what i have right now :

```
nssm install MDHIS_WebClient "%MDHIS2_HOME%/MDHIS_WebClient.cmd" AppDirectory %MDHIS2_HOME% DisplayName MDHIS_WebClient Start SERVICE_AUTO_START DependOnService MSSQLSERVER AppNoConsole 1 AppStopMethodConsole 30000
```

This works but the arguments are ignored.  Can anyone show me an example of the proper syntax?

Comment: More detailed examples can be found in offical site https://nssm.cc/usage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command you are using now will end up passing all of the items after the path to your program (starting with `AppDirectory`) as arguments to your program when it is executed.  Obviously that is not the behaviour that you want.

To establish parameters that are meaningful to `nssm` you must run a separate `nssm set` command for each parameter.  In this case you would use this command to create the service and define the path to your program:

```
  nssm install MDHIS_WebClient "%MDHIS2_HOME%/MDHIS_WebClient.cmd"
```

followed by this series of commands to establish the various parameters:

```
  nssm set MDHIS_WebClient AppDirectory %MDHIS2_HOME%

  nssm set MDHIS_WebClient DisplayName MDHIS_WebClient 

  nssm set MDHIS_WebClient Start SERVICE_AUTO_START 

  nssm set MDHIS_WebClient DependOnService MSSQLSERVER 

  nssm set MDHIS_WebClient AppNoConsole 1 

  nssm set MDHIS_WebClient AppStopMethodConsole 30000
```

To be safe, I would move the `Start` parameter to the end of that series in order to prevent the possibility of `nssm` launching the service before the remaining parameters (`DependOnService`, `AppNoConsole` and `AppStopMethodConsole`) have been established.

Comment: The nssm website made it seem like the first command would bring up the GUI which I didn't want since this script will be part of an installer but indeed this works just fine thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach.... i set nssm.exe to run as admin. Now it prompt for adminn in each set call from my batch. But at least it does no require shortcut or a different way to open an admin console. It isnt nice i know but its simpler.